# Julia: how to import a module

Tags: import, module, julia, juno-ide

I'm working with the language Julia and my IDE is [juno](http://junolab.org/).

Now I want to import my own module. Here is an example:

First I create a module file:

```
module my_module
export test
function test(id, name)
  print("Your ID:", id, ". Your name: ", name)
end
end
```

Its path is: `C:\doc\my_module.jl`

Now I want to import `my_module.jl` into another julia project. Here is the code:

```
import "C:\doc\my_module.jl"
```

It doesn't work and I got an error:

> invalid "import" statement: expected identifier

What should I do?

Comment: you can do `include("C:\doc\my_module.jl")`, then `import my_module`

Comment: Julia search default paths that exits in LOAD_PATH  environment variable for modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import a module, you need to `include` the file then import the module.

See the comment of @Gnimuc Key

There are still [other ways](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/) to import a module.

Comment: this is correct but misleading because is not mandatory for a module to first `include` then `import`, and after that, it's @Gnimuc answer, you can check the **community wiki** before sending another's answer.

Comment: @Thomas i put it as a comment because that works only for your specific case. in fact, there are several ways to import a module in julia depending on your use case, e.g. as @Reza mentioned above: add the path into `LOAD_PATH`. so you can edit your incorrect answer and give it fuller explanation. i'll definitely upvote it :)

Comment: @GnimucKey   :D  Well I just need to import a module dynamically so your method is enough. thanks.